# Using same Selenium webdriver for multiple actions on website?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am trying to create a GUI to modify a Javascript file on a website. It is used to create Leaflet markers without having to touch the code.

So my idea for the setup is that I first initiate the Webdriver and go to the respective JavaScript file in the first function.

```
def start():
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver")
    browser.get(---> move to the javascript file on the website)
    return browser
```

Then I want to have several other functions that can act on the textarea, like adding lines, deleting lines etc. The problem is that in the other functions I also have to use the "browser" variable from the start function:

```
def CreateMarker():
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    code = code.get()
    textarea = browser.find_element_by_class_name('textarea')
    textarea.send_keys(sending some keys)
    safe, yadada etc....
```

In the GUI (made with tkinter) I have one button bound to the start function to go the website and file and another button to add the marker code.

So the problem is, that the createmarker function doesnt recognize the browser variable and when I pass the variable in the CreateMarker function as CreateMarker(browser) it complains that "browser" is not defined, as soon as I want to run the GUI...

Comment: I don't see the argument in CreateMarker(). How do you pass the variable?

Comment: Okay I was able to get to the problem myself again. I took initiation to the mainfile and out of the function so it starts together with the program. Therefor the browser variable is defined there. Then I created a lambda function for the button command and it runs smoothly the way I want now :)

Comment: Can you please add the updated code and mark it as Answer? Might help someone with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I finally got everything to work the way I want. The cracking bit was just to make the webdriver a global variable and call that in the right way in the main function.

So now I have two buttons on the main GUI that look like this:

```
# Button to start the webdriver
Button(window, text = "Start", width=11, command=init.actions.start).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

# Textbox for what to write
Label (window, text='Enter text', bg="black", fg="white") .grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
text = Entry(window, width=20, bg="white")
text.grid(row=3, column =0, sticky=W)
```

And I have a separate file in which I store all the functions connected to the buttons. The functions to start the webdriver and to write the text to the textarea looks like this:

```
class actions:
    def start(): 
        from selenium import webdriver
        from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
        import time
        global browser 
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver")
        browser.get("go to the login page")
        login = browser.find_element_by_name("USER_LOGIN")
        login.send_keys("USERNAME HERE")
        pw= browser.find_element_by_name("USER_PASSWORD")
        pw.send_keys("PASSWORD HERE")
        pw.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(5)
        browser.get("page with the file")
        return browser

    def create_code(browser, text):
        from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
        Text=text.get()
        textarea.send_keys(Text)
```

So now I have a button to initialze the webdriver and a separate one to write to the file.